# org-mode how to hide tag name when exporting

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I have an org document with tags. However, when exporting it, the tag name is also exported. Is there a way to hide the tag name in the exported document?

```
    #+TITLE:     tag issue
    #+AUTHOR:    someone


    * First section
    ** sub
    bla bla bla
    ** second                                                                :incomplete:
    bla
```

Exported document:
[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can define how you want to export tags thanks to the **org-export-with-tags** variable:

> org-export-with-tags is a variable defined in ‘ox.el’. Its value is t
>
> This variable is safe as a file local variable if its value
>   satisfies the predicate which is a byte-compiled expression.
>
> Documentation: If nil, do not export tags, just remove them from
>   headlines.
>
> If this is the symbol ‘not-in-toc’, tags will be removed from table of
>   contents entries, but still be shown in the headlines of the document.
>
> This option can also be set with the OPTIONS keyword, e.g. "tags:nil".

In your case if you do not want to export tags, simply use the option:

```
#+OPTIONS: tags:nil
```

Your complete example is thus:

```
#+OPTIONS: tags:nil
#+TITLE:     tag issue
#+AUTHOR:    someone


* First section
** sub
   bla bla bla
** second                                                        :incomplete:
   bla
```

(before exporting with `C-e C-c p o`, do not forget to type `C-c C-c` over the line `#+OPTIONS: ...` to tell to emacs to refresh the setting)

You will get:

[image]

---

**note:** you can find other useful options [here](https://orgmode.org/manual/Export-settings.html)